# cron ignores variables defined in ".bashrc" and ".bash_profile"

Tags: bash, cron

I have defined "SHELL" variable in /etc/crontab file:

```
[martin@martin ~]$ grep SHELL /etc/crontab 
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
[martin@martin ~]$ file /usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (FreeBSD), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for FreeBSD 8.0 (800107), stripped
[martin@martin ~]$
```

In addition, all my scripts in /etc/crontab file are started under user "martin". However */home/martin/.bash_profile*(for login shell) and */home/martin/.bashrc*(for non-logging shell) contain some variables which are ignored in case of cron job, but are used in case I log into machine over SSH or open new bash session. Why cron ignores those variables? Isn't cron simply executing "/usr/local/bin/bash my-script.sh" with permissions for user "martin"?

Comment: Ubuntu users may like to note that Ubuntu's default `.bashrc` has [a line that stops it from running](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080812/133393) in non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can source the file you want at the top of the script or beginning of the job for the user that is executing the job. The "source" command is a built-in. You'd do the same thing if you made edits to those files to load the changes.

```
* * * * * source /home/user/.bash_profile; <command>
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/.bash_profile

<commands>
```

Comment: Note that "source" might not work if cron is not using the `bash` shell. I've added an answer that can handle the case when the shell is `sh`.

Comment: ^ [source not found error fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975370/help-with-basic-shell-script-bin-sh-source-not-found)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc it is not working for me. .bashrc won't work ?

Comment: if `source` does not work, then try  `.`. Example; `. /home/user/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 28):

Because it's not an interactive shell. The same happens when you open some terminals.

Have a look at this question: [What is the .bashrc file? | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file)

And also at this one:

[What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)

Different scripts fire depending on if the connection is a login shell (or not), an interactive shell (or not), or both.

If you want to make bashrc you'll need to make this change:

> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>   example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
>   expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
>   the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the
>   following command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.
>
> As noted above, if a non-interactive shell is invoked with the `--login` option, Bash attempts to read and execute commands from the login shell startup files.

Source: [Bash Startup Files | Bash Reference Manual | gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Comment: So if we set BASH_ENV inside Cron, cron bash scripts will source that because cron is non-interactive and non-login.

Answer (score 23):

You may not be able to run `source` if the `sh` shell is being used. This can be changed by adding the following line in your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * source "/root/.bashrc"; <command>
```

You can also specify the environment:

```
BASH_ENV="/root/.bashrc"
* * * * * <command>
```

or you can use your local `/home/user/.bashrc` if it is a user cron job (e.g. `crontab -e`).

Note that `.bash_profile` can replace `.bashrc`, if it exists.

Credit: [How to change cron shell (sh to bash)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash)

Comment: this works well also for Acquia Cloud Scheduled jobs, which are basically cron jobs. You can do the same, like: ```SHELL=/bin/bash && source /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bash_profile && sh .... ```

Comment: Does SHELL=/bin/bash apply only to the cron that immediately follows, to all those that follow, or to the whole /etc/crontab?

Answer (score 12):

You could invoke bash with the `-l` option, like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l /path/to/script arg1 arg2
```

The `-l` option makes bash a *login* shell. Thus, it will read the user's `.bash_profile`. It won't read the user's `.bashrc` unless it is explicitly sourced by `.bash_profile`. This is because non-interactive shells don't automatically read `.bashrc`.  But you shouldn't need `.bashrc` for a cron job. `.bashrc` is for setting things useful to *interactive* shells, like setting `PS1` and creating aliases.

**Variations:**

If bash is on the PATH, there's no need to specify an absolute path to it:

```
* * * * * bash -l /path/to/script arg1 arg2
```

An optimization would be to replace the current shell by using `exec`:

```
* * * * * exec bash -l /path/to/script arg1 arg2
```

See [Why do some Linux shell scripts use exec to run commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286378) for discussion of the use of `exec`.

Answer (score 10):

Something else that might interfere with the sourcing of your `.bashrc` from a cronjob is any checks that this file does in order to detect interactive shells.

For example, on Ubuntu 18.04, the default `.bashrc` for a user starts with this:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

and so sourcing it won't do anything useful since it will exit immediately.

Comment: This turned out to be critical for me. I moved the relevant portion of my `.bashrc` into `.bash_profile`, updated the file path in my cronjob, and suddenly the same cron command worked.

Comment: `bash -i` starts an interactive shell. `bash -lic 'some bash code'` is a useful recipe.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` acts differently whether it is a **shell** or a normal **programming language** (like `perl` or `python`).

By design, the settings in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc. are for users to set things when `bash` plays **the role of a shell** (login shell, interractive shell). Think about environment you have in a `xterm` (interactive shell) or in `ssh` sessions (login shell) or in consoles (login shell).

In other hand, `bash` is also a powerful **progamming language** –think about many scripts for managing services in `systemd`– which requires a different style of working. For example, when a developer is writing a system script or a `bash` program, he/she will not like to source the user's `~/.bash_profile` automatically. It is a normal program, not a shell. A normal program (including `bash` programs) would naturally **inherit** settings from the current working evironement (shell), but not **set** them.

If we write a program for `cron` in `bash` –it just happens to be written in `bash`; in fact, we can write it in `python` or `perl` or any other progamming language– then we can have an option to sources `bash`'s `~/.bash_profile` (read: setting of user's shell, which just happens to be the same language of your programming language):

```
[ -f /home/user/.bash_profile ] && . /home/user/.bash_profile
```

However, what if that particular user do not use `bash` as his/her shell? He/she may use `zsh`, `ksh`, `fish`, etc. So, that practice would not really work when writing program for public use.

So, you can source `~/.bash_profile` if you think that will work. But, here, it is not about whether we are able to source a file, it is about how things should works in the system: **the design concept**. In short: **we should view `bash` as something having 2 roles: shell and progamming language**. Then everything will be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when executing a node application from cron which uses NVM , In order to make bash shell to read the .bashrc file from cron just envoke the bash command with interactive shell option `-l.

eg: `* * * * * /bin/bash -lc '/home/user/myapp.sh restart'`

If that doesn't work try setting path variable in crontab

```
41 7 * * * /bin/bash -lc "PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin && /home/user/script.sh restart "
```

Answer (score -1):

My way to deal with it was this:

**1)** Putting my variables in (the end of) `~/.profile`:

```
myVarInDotProfile="someValue"
```

**2)** Creating a Bash script for my (daily) cron tasks (`~/cronDaily.sh`) containing my commands plus repetitive sourcing of `~/.profle`:

```
source ~/.profile
command ${myVarInDotProfile}/
```

**3)** scheduling my script's execution from `crontab`, to run daily:

```
0 0 * * * bash ~/cronDaily.sh
```

My variable wasn't ignored and the commands ran successfully.

---

Some may say such intense sourcing of `~/.profile` is problematic. In my particular case I don't see why it is a problem but I would advice to consider creating a dedicated file for that.

In general, there might be a better way to this but that's what worked for me after a lot of pain and it explains the principle that as of Bash 4.3.46, you cannot source a file from `crontab`.