# How to change cron shell (sh to bash)?

Tags: shell, cron

Is it possible to make commands in crontab run with bash instead of sh? I know you can pass commands to bash with `-c`, but that's annoying and I never use sh anyway.

Comment: don't really know what you're doing (not familiar with cron) but if you are running a script then adding a shebang to it should work, not sure if I am correct.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You should be able to set the environment variable prior to the cron job running:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
5 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/daily.job >> $HOME/tmp/out 2>&1
```

Comment: is it possible to also make it read .bashrc?

Comment: @Fluffy `.bashrc` is - by definition - for *interactive* shells; so when started via `cron`, `bash` will only read this file if it is an *interactive shell*.

Comment: @umläute, ok, so where should I put env vars that should exist in non-interactive non-login shells?

Comment: I was able to make it read bashrc by adding `BASH_ENV="/root/.bashrc"`. Thanks

Comment: @Fluffy you should make that an answer

Comment: Regarding `.bashrc`, `bash -l` looks useful, http://blog.endpoint.com/2015/02/cron-wrapper-keep-your-cron-jobs.html

Comment: Note that I've observed that `SHELL` requires to be set in each crontab (e.g. the one you modify with `crontab -e`) and setting it only in `/etc/crontab` won't apply globally.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel that's correct, the system crons and user crontabs (`crontab -e`) are independent from each other

Comment: Will this apply to the entire cron file? Or just the remaining jobs in the crontab lexically?

Comment: I wonder if I can do `SHELL=/bin/sh 2>/tmp/cron_errors.log`. Finding errors in cron jobs is a pain. Am trying now.

Comment: /usr/bin/bash vs  /bin/bash