# Does cron impose some limitations to types of commands and privilege of execution?

Tags: command-line, cron, bash-script

I've experienced an issue where some of my scripts run perfectly fine when I call them manually, but these same scripts when called as cron jobs via `cron` don't seem to work at all.

**So my question:** I'd like to know if there are restrictions that apply with the use of commands and/or scripts (and the privilege of execution) in a script scheduled to run with `cron`?

Comment: How are you setting these cron jobs up? Using `crontab -e` as a user or are you adding them to your system's `/etc/cron*` directories and/or files?

Comment: I use the `crontab` command..

Comment: OK, so the cron jobs you're setting up are running as your userid, so the only thing you have to deal with is a difference in environments when running the script vs. running it in a cron. I believe you can also do this to get a Bash environment up and running via your crontab. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason why commands that work fine from the command line would fail under `cron` is the fact they run under a stripped down environment with only a handful of variables defined.

In particular `PATH` is set to its default value.

Any customization done in dot files (`.profile` `/etc/profile` and the likes) is not done with cron scripts but of course, this can be fixed by modifiying the `cron` entry or the called script itself.

The fact the script is non interactive and missing a graphic environment (`DISPLAY` variable) might also affect scripts to run as expected.