# Linux crontab -- which shell am I using

Tags: bash, shell, cron, csh

In crontab, how do I know which shell it is using?

for example if I want to redirect output how do I know if I need to use &> or >& (bash vs csh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change cron shell (sh to bash)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash)

Comment: Incidentally, bash supports `>&`, so if this is the only difference you're worried about just use that form. It also has the advantage that it's a clear error in shells that do not support it, whereas `&>` may simply start the process in the background with no redirection and create a blank file.

Comment: In general, you can assume that all those system utilities use a POSIX `sh`, and that you cannot assume any features that are not specified in POSIX.

Answer (score 10):

From `crontab(5)`:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8)
>         daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from
>         the /etc/passwd line of the crontab´s owner.  HOME and SHELL can be
>         overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME can not.

Comment: I wonder if there are cron daemons that don't allow setting environment variables in crontab..

Answer (score 2):

It depends what version of `cron` you have, and how it is configured, but usually it is `/bin/sh`. Often that is a symlink to something else though, but that is easy to find as you can simply run `ls -l /bin/sh`.

You could add a cron entry like:

```
* *    * * *    ps -p $$ > /tmp/shelltest
```

or (if editing `/etc/crontab` instead of adding an entry to a per-user crontab as done via `crontab -e`):

```
* *    * * *    username    ps -p $$ > /tmp/shelltest
```

which will tell you via output to `/tmp/shelltest` the filename of the shell. If your `cron` is properly setup to mail output to you then you can skip the `>/tmp/shelltest` to get the information by mail instead of it being dropped into a file.

To be a bit more trixy something like:

```
* *    * * *    ls -l /proc/`ps -p $$ | tail -n 1 | xargs | cut -f 1 -d \ `/exe > /tmp/shelltest
```

should tell you the exact file used. On a typical Debian system this will result in something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dspillett dspillett 0 Mar 14 16:17 /proc/1356/exe -> /bin/dash
```

showing that cron is using `dash` as the default shell in this instance.

To break that command down:

- `ps -p $$` outputs details of the current process (well, `ps`'s parent process) which will be the shell in this case.
- `tail -n 1` strips away the header row that `ps` includes
- piping through `xargs` is a trick to trim off leading spaces from the line
- the `cut` invocation takes the first field from the like where the deliter is spaces (it is absolutely vital that you include the space between the \ and the backtick)
- wrapping that in backticks includes the output (which should be a process ID) in the outer command line which becomes...
- `ls -l /proc/9999/exe` where "9999" is the process ID read from `ps` which lists the file used to create the process because in the '/proc' filesystem `/proc/<pid>/exe` is a link to the executable of the process identified by <pid>.
- <sup><sub>(there may be a more concise way to do the same thing, that was typed from memory, suggestions welcome via comments!)</sub></sup>

Comment: `ps -p $$ --no-headers -o '%P'` shows the parent ID of the process whose value is in $$