# Shell script is not working via cron job

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I'm using a script which is working in Stand alone and is not working through the cron job .

```
qexma1@test:bin> head -n 10 test.sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -r PATH='/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin'
source $AEM_CONFIG/aem-wrap.conf
```

Cron Job :

```
qexma1@test:bin> crontab -l | grep aem-test.sh
01 15 * * * bin/test.sh -b ; touch bin/crontest.txt;
```

Flag :

```
qexma1@test:bin> ll bin/ | grep cron
-rw-r--r--  1 qexma1 abc   0 Nov 11 15:01 crontest.txt
```

Flag file got created crontest.txt but script didn't get executed. Permissions 0755

Comment: Suggest you replace `/global/appaem/aem/bin/aem-test.sh -b` with `/global/appaem/aem/bin/aem-test.sh -b >/tmp/mylog 2>&1` and then update question with the output recorded in /tmp/mylog.  Where/how are you expecting `$AEM_CONFIG` to be getting initialised ?

Comment: $AEM_CONFIG is a Environment variable and part of a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output to stderr is as below, it means variable `$AEM_CONFIG` is not getting set.  That is why the job fails.

```
/global/appaem/aem/bin/aem-test.sh: line 5: /aem-wrap.conf: No such file or directory
```

To fix the issue, revise the script to source the relevant file that sets `$AEM_CONFIG`.

As you point out the variable is defined in .bashrc, see [cron ignores variables defined in “.bashrc” and “.bash_profile”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile).  You need to add a line such as `source ~/.bashrc` into your script.  Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -r PATH='/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin'
source ~/.bashrc
source $AEM_CONFIG/aem-wrap.conf
```

Comment: any idea why environment variable is not being picked $AEM_CONFIG??

Comment: Where/how are you expecting `$AEM_CONFIG` to be getting initialised ?  It is not initialised and set to any value in the script info seen so far.

Comment: It's environment var. configured under .bashrc
`echo $AEM_CONFIG
/global/appaem/aem/etc/aem-config`

Comment: `.bashrc` is not run via cron.  Answer revised to make this clear and offer solution.