# crontab doesn't get bash.bashrc variables

Tags: cron, variable, bashrc

In Ubuntu 16.04 Bash 4.3.46(1) at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` I declared the following variable:

```
drt="/var/www/html"
```

I sourced the file (`source /etc/bash.bashrc`)

I executed `crontab -e` and added just for testing `* * * * * touch /var/www/html/myFile.sh`. This worked, while `* * * * * touch ${drt}/myFile.sh` didn't.

If a variable declared in `bash.bashrc` is global why it doesn't get processed by `crontab`?

### Update1

I don't want to duplicate the stream `drt="/var/www/html"` into `crontab` (or `cron.d`) to avoid redundancy by principle.

### Update2

I followed [this session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile) and it seems the answer marked as correct didn't solve my problem.

The [second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67942/258010) was somewhat unclear to me - why to put this conditional statement in (some?) `bashrc` file.

I also tried the third solution in relation to `bash.bashrc` (added `SHELL=/bin/bash` into the very start of `crontab`, saved the file and sourced `bash.bashrc` but had no change in a `* * * * * touch ~/myfiile` test.

I thus ask to reopen this question, or at least, clarify one the answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables defined in `*.bashrc` are global only in the sense that they can be read out by programs running in the shell, and that they are handled specially by the shell. Whether a program reads these environmental variables and how they interpret them is completely dependent on the design and there is not regulation stating how a program should handle environment variables.

In short, the way `cron` interprets the crontab is decided by the program `cron` itself. It decides not to read the "global" environment variables and use its own syntax to define the "environment variables" instead. That's by design. If you can understand why we cannot just use `${drt}` in a `CMakeLists.txt`, you should be able to understand why `${drt}` in a crontab does not do what you expect it to do.

You can, of course, add the following line to your **crontab** if you wish.

```
drt="/var/www/html"
```

Comment: This isn't entirely true. bashrc is only read by interactive shells, that's why cron doesn't use it.